# How to resolve this error in Streamlit app

Tags: python, streamlit

I am coding in Python to be run on streamlit, when I use IF argument, it give me error.

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

st.write("Welcome to my Sample Suvery App!")

age = st.text_input("What is your age?",
              "Please enter your age here correctly",)
if age > 12:
    name = st.text_input("What is your full name:"
                    "Enter your full name")
    sex = st.selectbox("Male", "Female")
    phone_number = st.number_input("Enter your phone number:")
    father_name = st.text_input("what's your father name?"
                                "Enter father's name")
    mother_name = st.text_input("what's your mother name?"
                                "Enter Mother's name")
    address = st.text_input("where do you live? "
                            "Enter your current address")
while age <= 12:
    st.write("You are not qualify for this suvrey")

    break

st.button("submit", type="primary")

result = st.write(f"{name}")
st.write(f"{result}," "Thanks for your time")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is this line:

```
age = st.text_input("What is your age?",
              "Please enter your age here correctly",)
```

This sets `age = "Please enter your age here correctly"` when the app first renders, which will cause a `TypeError` because the app will then immediately try to  run `if age > 12`.

I think it would make more sense to set the initial value to an empty string `""`, and use the argument `placeholder="Please enter your age here correctly"`. I went ahead and made this change to your other `st.text_input` widgets as well, and added some basic error handling so that the user cannot enter non-numeric values for the age.

I also structured the app so that the other text inputs don't show up until the age is entered correctly (you can modify this as you like).

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

st.write("Welcome to my Sample Survey App!")

age = st.text_input("What is your age?",
            value="",
            placeholder="Please enter your age here correctly",)

## basic error handling
if age != "":
    try: 
        age = float(age)
        if age > 12:
            name = st.text_input("What is your full name:",
                            value="",
                            placeholder="Enter your full name")
            sex = st.selectbox(label="Gender", options=["Male", "Female"])
            phone_number = st.text_input("Enter your phone number:")
            father_name = st.text_input("what's your father name?",
                                        placeholder="Enter father's name")
            mother_name = st.text_input("what's your mother name?",
                                        placeholder="Enter Mother's name")
            address = st.text_input("where do you live? ",
                                    placeholder="Enter your current address")

            if name != "":
                if st.button("submit", type="primary"):
                    st.write(f"{name}, " "Thanks for your time")
        else:
            st.write("You are not qualified for this suvrey")
    except:
        st.error("Please enter a valid age")
```

[image]